# convert arraylist type

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class `Line` that contains an internal `ArrayList<Double>`. In my program, I have an `ArrayList<Line>` that contains many `Line` objects.

In my program, I want to be able to create a new `ArrayList<Double>` that contains the content of the `ArrayList<Double>` from all the `Line`s in my `ArrayList<Line>`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Here is my code...

```
class Line {
    ArrayList<Double> values;

    line() {
        values = new ArrayList<Double>();
    }

public class Calucating{
    ArrayList<Line> lineY = new ArrayList<Line>();

    // Adding lines in here...

    // Now I want to add the contents of each Line into a single ArrayList<Double>
    ArrayList<Double> lineNewY=new ArrayList<Double>;
}
```

How can I easily join the content of all my `Line`s into a single `ArrayList<Double>`?

Comment: Nope. Not clear. Is there a question?

Comment: It's not clear. You'll get better answers if you formulate a clear question, and also if you format your code properly (hint: there is a preview panel!)

Comment: So you have an array of lines, each line containing an array of doubles, and you want to get one large array of doubles that contains all the doubles in all the arrays in the lines, is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have an array of lines, each line containing an array of doubles, and you want to get one large array of doubles that contains all the doubles in all the arrays in the lines.

```
class Line {
    ArrayList<Double> values = new ArrayList<Double>();
}

public class Calculating {
    ArrayList<Line> lineY = new ArrayList<Line>();

    void someMethod() {
        ArrayList<Double> lineNewY = new ArrayList<Double>;
        for( Line line : lineY )
            lineNewY.addAll( line.values );

        // lineNewY now has all the doubles
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Very much sir. I really appriciate your help