# Two different ArrayList merge?

Tags: java, android

```
private ArrayList<SublistLocalData> catList;

private ArrayList<Localdata> nameList ,nameList1;
```

Both having the different-different data:

```
for(SublistLocalData  list: catList )
nameList1.addAll( list.nameList );
```

I am trying this concept for add the one type arrayList data into a different type ArrayList, I follow this link:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219527/convert-arraylist-type)

What should i do to solve this ?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: What are you trying to solve?

Comment: [Do I look like a guru?](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/The_Guru_Myth)

Comment: @baraky : I want to add the catList data into the nameList1 data into a  ArrayList<Localdata> nameList . this is my question ?

Comment: @NandakishoreK : for(SublistLocalData  list: catList )
nameList1.addAll( list.nameList );

Comment: @NandakishoreK : I tried this but getting the error. I add a link for this I follow

Comment: How about adding the error you get?

Answer (score 5):

Question `What should i do to solve this ?`

Answer: Find a tutorial about [Collection framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) in Java and read it.

If you want to store objects of different type in single list, you should create a list that can accept any object. Every object in Java inherit from  `Object` class. Therefore you need to create something like:

```
private List<Object> list4Everything = new ArrayList<>();
```

EDIT:

How ever if you have same object and you just want to merge two already existing list into new single one. You should use the method [List#addAll(Collection c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

Lest do it on example, we will have three lists:

```
private List<YourType> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
private List<YourType> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
private List<YourType> mergeResult = new ArrayList<>();
```

You have various option to insert all data from `list1` and 'list2' into `mergeResult`

Option 1 - Using addAll of megeResult.

```
mergeResult.addAll(list1);
mergeResult.addAll(list2);
```

Option 2 - Do it by hand.

```
for(YourType yt : list1) { //Itereate throug every item from list1
   mergerResult.add(yt); //Add found item to mergerResult
}

for(YourType yt : list1) { //Itereate throug every item from list2
   mergerResult.add(yt); //Add found item to mergerResult
}
```

Note: In this solution you have possibility to select witch item is added to `meregeResult`.

So for example if we would like to have distinct result we could do something like this.

```
for(YourType yt : list1) { //Itereate throug every item from list1
  if(mergerResult.contains(yt) == false) { //We check that item, already exits in mergeResult
     mergerResult.add(yt); //Add found item to mergerResult
  }
}

for(YourType yt : list1) { //Itereate throug every item from list2
  if(mergerResult.contains(yt) == false) { //We check that item, already exits in mergeResult
   mergerResult.add(yt); //Add found item to mergerResult
   }
}
```

---

As we perform twice the same operation we could create a utilities class.

```
public static <T> boolean addAllNotContained(Collection<? super T> traget, Collection<? super T> source) {

   //We should assure first that target or source are not null

   int targetSize = target.size();

   for(T item: source) {
     if(target.contains(item) == false) {
        target.add(item);
     }
   }

   return targetSize != target.size();
}
```

Note: To have similar result of distinct merge you could use jest [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). It is created to not store duplicates.

The another option is too use already created framework that extend default Java one. The options are [guava with iterables](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/package-summary.html) and [apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/)

Comment: I use an ArrayList , can I merge the data of two different array into a one different arrayList

Comment: @user2078315, ArrayList is just implementation of List interface.

Comment: yes an array list is a list. like he said please read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/ will take sometime but you will learn useful things

Comment: i tried but getting the same error on nameList1.addAll(catList); In which  nameList is a list<Local> and catList is List<sublist> type

Comment: So you have two different types. You must go with `List<Object>`

Answer (score 0):

If there are any realtionships between SublistLocalData class and the Localdata class you can create a class that is a super class both of them or an Interface which the two classes implements.
Say you have this class : `class AbstractSuperClass {}`
Then : Here how to declare a list of the superClass : `List<AbstractSuperClass> list;`
Using this list, you can add any type of AbstractSuperClass (classes that inherits from it like SublistLocalData  and Localdata )
You can then write :

```
list.add(new SublistLocalData());

orlist.add(new Localdata());
```